# Integrating $\int_{\sqrt{2}}^2 \frac{1}{t^3\sqrt{t^2-1}}\,dt$.

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

I am trying to compute
$$
\int_{\sqrt{2}}^2 \frac{1}{t^3\sqrt{t^2-1}}\,dt.
$$

This is what I got so far:

$t=\sec(x)$ and $dt=\sec(x)\tan(x)x\,dx$

So plugging this in gives me 
$$
\int \frac{1}{\sec^3(x)}\cdot\sqrt{\sec^2(x)-1}\sec(x)\tan(x)\,dx.
$$
By my trig property $1+\tan^2(x)=\sec^2(x)$, I get
$$
\int \frac{1}{\sec^3(x)\tan(x)}\sec(x)\tan(x)\,dx.
$$
Then I simplify and get
$$
\int \frac{1}{\sec^2(x)}\,dx.
$$
By the trig property I get
$$
\int\cos^2(x)\,dx.
$$
Then I get $(x/2)+(1/4)\sin(2x).$

So now I need to get back to my original variable so I solve for $x$:

$t=\sec(x)$ and $x=\mathrm{arcsec}(t)$.

It's this part I'm confused about. I don't know what step to take next. I know I am supposed to draw my triangle, I just don't know how to get there.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use LaTeX or Mathjax to format your question.

Comment: @graydad Lighten up a bit when it's a first time user, please. At the very least, provide a link to the tutorial. Some folks have never heard of mathjax.

Comment: Are LaTeX and Mathjax websites

Comment: It's a way to typeset equations and mathematics to display nicely. See [mathjax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/75064)

Comment: @JessicaGarciaTejeda as amWhy says, and it works great for this website. I didn't mean to come off as overly critical, so I apologize for that.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial.

Comment: In the future I will use Mathjax. I'm currently on a tablet device and am a new user of MSE. Thank you for sharing that Aaron.

Comment: Let's not all forget that LaTeX is much more than just for typesetting beautiful mathematics. It's so much more than that.

Answer (score 2):

$t=\sec(x)$

You can build a right triangle for this to translate your answer in terms of $t$ to in terms of $x$.

### Also here's a hint: $\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$

oops didn't realize it was a definite integral

Answer (score 2):

there is no need to go back to the original variable. you could change the limits of integration at the same time like:

change of variable: $t = 1/\cos x, dt = \frac{\sin x}{\cos^2 x} dx$  and at $t = \sqrt 2, x = \pi/4$ and $t = 2, x = \pi/3$

$$\int_{\sqrt 2}^2 \dfrac{1}{t^3\sqrt{t^2 - 1}} \ dt = 
\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/3} \cos^2 x \ dx
 =  \frac{1}{2}\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/3} (1 + \cos 2x) \ dx
$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=\cosh t$, and use the fact that $\cosh^2t-\sinh^2t=1$, along with $\cosh't=\sinh t$ and $\sinh't=\cosh t$. You'll get $$I=\int\frac{\sinh t}{\cosh^3t\cdot\sinh t}dt=\int\frac1{\cosh^3t}dt=\int\frac{\cosh t}{\cosh^4t}dt=\int\frac{d(\sinh t)}{(1+\sinh^2t)^2}=\int\frac{du}{(1+u^2)^2}$$ which is trivial. $($Of course, you'll have to pay attention to evaluating the new limits of integration at each substitution$)$.

Answer (score 2):

By substituting $u=\sqrt{t^2-1}$ you get using $\newcommand{\dd}{\; \mathrm{d}}\dd u = \frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2-1}} \dd t$ and $t^2=u^2+1$ that
$$\int \frac1{t^3\sqrt{t^2-1}} \dd t= \int \frac1{t^4} \cdot \frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2-1}} \dd t = \int \frac1{(u^2+1)^2} \dd u.$$
(So in the end this seems just as a variation of Lucian's answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest thing to do at this point is to use that for $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$,

$\;\;\;\sec x=\sqrt{2}\implies \cos x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\implies x=\frac{\pi}{4}$ and

$\;\;\;\sec x=2\implies \cos x=\frac{1}{2}\implies x=\frac{\pi}{3}$.

---

Alternatively, you can use $t=\sec x\implies\cos x=\frac{1}{t}$ and $\sin x=\frac{\sqrt{t^2-1}}{t}$ $\;\;$if $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$,

and $\sin 2x=2\sin x\cos x$.

Comment: I though that I couldn't just do that because I changed the variable. So because I changed the variable, I can't use the original bounds.

Comment: You can either change the limits and then use the antiderivative you have (in terms of x), or you can write the antiderivative in terms of t and then use the original limits.